# Best subset selection

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, binary-programming

> Consider an $n \times d$ data matrix $D$ in which you want to find
> the best subset of $k$ features that are related to the $n$-dimensional regressand vector $y$. Therefore, the following mixed integer program is formulated with $d$-dimensional real
> vector $w$, $d$-dimensional binary vector $z$, and an a priori (constant) upper bound $M$ on each coefficient in $w$. The optimization problem is to minimize $\|Dw − y\|^2$ subject
> to the following constraints:
> $$z \in \{0, 1\}^d, \quad w \le Mz, \quad 1^Tz = k$$
> The notation $1$ denotes a $d$-dimensional vector of $1$s. Propose an algorithm using block coordinate descent for this problem, where each optimized block contains just two integer variables and all real variables.

---

I have never deal with block coordinate descent. Should I treat the $z=0$ and $z=1$ as separate blocks and optimize two problems separately using Lagrangian? If no then how should one identify the blocks and what should be done with them.

I just managed to find that the block coordinate descent is the same coordinate descent but with the usage of blocks. However, I don't get how to identify those blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a feasible solution with $z=\hat{z}$, define a block by choosing a pair $(i,j)$ with $\hat{z}_i=1$ and $\hat{z}_j=0$.  Now fix $z_i=0$, $z_j=1$, and $z_\ell=\hat{z}_\ell$ for $\ell\not\in\{i,j\}$.  Solve the ordinary least-squares regression problem with the regressors prescribed by $z$.  If the new objective value is better, keep the new $z$ vector; otherwise revert back to $z_i=1$ and $z_j=0$.  Repeat until no pair yields an improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. May I ask you how did you come up with this particular solution? Is this the only possible solution (and you specifically know it) or are there some other approaches on how to tackle the problem? I am asking these because I don't fully understand the concept of how one defines a desired block.

Comment: This is the only solution for which each block contains two integer variables and all real variables.  If the block were to instead satisfy $z_i=z_j$, there would be no freedom for the block solver to change the $z$ variables and still satisfy $1^T z=k$.